# Kafka Streams: Aggregate suppressed values into list and expose resulting list as KTable

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to aggregate values into a list and then expose them as a KTable so that I can later join them with a KStream. My KTable topology is:

```kotlin
val builder = StreamsBuilder()
builder.stream(
        inputTopic,
        Consumed.with<String, AvroObject>(Topology.AutoOffsetReset.EARLIEST)
            .withKeySerde(serde.stringKeySerde)
            .withValueSerde(serde.avroObjectSerde),
    )
        .selectKey({ _, value -> value.id }, Named.`as`("key-mapper"))
        .groupByKey(Grouped.`as`("group-by-key"))
        .windowedBy(SlidingWindows.ofTimeDifferenceAndGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(20), Duration.ofSeconds(5)))
        .aggregate(
            { mutableListOf() },
            { _, value, aggregate ->
                aggregate.add(value)
                aggregate
            },
            Materialized.`as`<String, MutableList<AvroObject>, WindowStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>("list-store")
                .withKeySerde(serde.stringKeySerde)
                .withValueSerde(serde.avroObjectListSerde),

        )
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()).withName("list-suppress"))
        .toStream { key, _ -> key.key() }
        .toTable(
            Named.`as`("table"),
            Materialized.`as`<String, MutableList<AvroObject>>(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("table-store"))
                .withKeySerde(serde.stringKeySerde)
                .withValueSerde(serde.avroObjectListSerde),
        )
```

However, when I'm running a unit test I am only getting a list containing the last input event. It seems that the topology is not aggregating at all. The unit test looks as following (assume that the `TestDriver` and other variables are setup properly):

```kotlin
@Test
    fun `Expose list of AvroObjects`() {
        // Arrange
        val id = "common-mrid"

        val avroObject1 = recordFactory.generateAvroObject(id = id)
        val avroObject2 = recordFactory.generateAvroObject(id = id)
        val dummy = recordFactory.generateAvroObject(id = "dummy")

        // Act
        inputTopic.pipeInput(id, avroObject1, 1_000)
        inputTopic.pipeInput(id, avroObject2, 2_000)
        inputTopic.pipeInput(dummy.id, dummy, 40_000)    // Dummy event to trigger suppress release

        // Assert
        // Expecting list containing two elements/records, but the list is only containing avroObject2
    }
```

Is there something wrong with my topology? Or is there another reason for the undesired behavior?

Comment: Everything works as expected if I update the timestamp for the DummyEvent to be `27_000`. Why is that? It looks like there must be a time difference between the last record and the DummyEvent of a maximum of windowSize + gracePeriod. Why? Can someone please elaborate on how sliding windows work?